# I can't add a New library in Blender 2.8

Tags: workflow, blend-files

I want to create my own library in order to have access to very complicated shading materials in all my projects. 
So I go to materials, click "+" in Material Library VX, and then when I click "OK" an error message says "select a library" which makes no sense to me.

But whatever, I select Cycles library and try again. Blender tells me "Library added" but I can't see it even if I close and launch Blender again.

I know we can append materials from files but in the long run it's not possible for me to work without my library.

I really want a library for my own materials so please help :/

Answer (score 2):

## Why?

When you try to  create a new library with the add-on, it tries to create a new .blend file and since the add-on's directory is in Program Files folder(if you are on Windows) it does not have permissions to do so and fails.

## Solutions

You could run Blender with administrative privileges by right-clicking it and choosing Run as administrator. This way it gains permissions to write the file in the current add-on's folder.

**Or even better solotion**

You could move the add-on from

`C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons`

to

`C:\Users\[Your User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\`

where it will be able to write the files when started normally. Note that you have to move the add-on's folder (in this case `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\materials_library_vx\`), and not copy it since if you had it in both places you would have a conflict.